# wp7 change background color of control on control disable

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

i want to change the backgroundcolor of a datepicker when it is disable.

i tried to change the background but

it is not changing when it is disabled

how to change it?

Comment: Try enabling the control long enough to change the background , then set it back to disabled, orelse set the controls background before disabling it.

Comment: Post the code you used for your "attempt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Expression Blend to edit the Control template of the DatePicker, then find the Button inside the template and edit it's template.
With the template selected open the 'states' panel, select the disabled state and edit the ButtonBackground's background brush property to your desired colour.